# Meteorjs's built in mongodb located in linux vm, How to access by external app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor's built in Mongo uses the application port plus one (Meteor on port 3000 = Mongo on port 3001; Meteor on 3009 = Mongo on port 3010).

I have tried to telnet as below result.
Meteor on port 3000 = success
Mongo on port 3001  = fail

Anyone know is there any possible way to connect from outside vm, not localhost. thanks

Comment: change the host of the app, because by default it just accept connection from localhost, or you can do a SSH tunnel.

Comment: @RicardoAragão May i know where the host to change?

Comment: I can not find any document about allowing external connection into Meteor's Mongodb

Comment: You can use `--port` argument. Ex:`--port 192.168.86.250:4000`

Comment: As i know --port is for the meteor web, not for the mongodb, am i correct?

Comment: Yes and no. When you set the port to meteor, you are setting it to mongo too. Because Mongo will work in the Meteor port + 1, and use the same IP address. When you don't set the IP, it will be localhost.

Comment: So you mean that, if i Port forward --port to internet, also open Mongo to public access try?